# "aws s3 cp" gets error while "aws s3 ls" works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Our client shared a S3 bucket to us. The following command to list the objects works.

```bash
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=... AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=... aws s3 ls s3://bucket/company4/obj1
```

But it got 403 error when downloading?

```bash
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=... AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=... aws s3 cp s3://bucket/company4/obj1 .
```

> fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

---

The issue was caused by missing proxy. It works after setting the proxy `export http_proxy=...`. Why `aws s3 ls` doesn't require proxy?

Comment: Does this file exist anymore?

Comment: It could be that the bucket has a bucket policy that allows list operations and denies fetching operations.

Comment: Look at this it might help https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/

Comment: Can you confirm that was the case? I'll post an answer

Comment: I resolved the issue by setting the `https_proxy` environment variable.